# Recursive types issue

Tags: scala, recursion, playframework, graphql, sangria

I defined two types Food and Type, where 1 Type has N Foods and I used `lazy` to make [recursive types](http://sangria-graphql.org/learn/#circular-references-and-recursive-types) work.

```
lazy val FoodType: ObjectType[Unit, FoodData] = ObjectType(
  "Food",
  "The details of a food",
  interfaces[Unit, FoodData](nodeInterface),
  idFields[FoodData] ++
    fields[Unit, FoodData](
      Field("name", StringType, resolve = _.value.name),
      Field("image", OptionType(StringType),
        description = Some("Image CDN URL"),
        resolve = _.value.image),
      Field("type", TypeType, resolve = c => types.defer(c.value.type_id))
    ))

lazy val TypeType: ObjectType[Unit, TypeData] = ObjectType(
  "Type",
  "The details of a type",
  interfaces[Unit, TypeData](nodeInterface),
  idFields[TypeData] ++
    fields[Unit, TypeData](
      Field("name", StringType, resolve = _.value.name),
      Field("foods", ListType(FoodType), resolve = c => foods.deferRelSeq(byType, c.value.id))
    ))
```

But I get the following error.

```
Uncaught error from thread [application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-32] shutting down JVM since 'akka.jvm-exit-on-fatal-error' is enabled for ActorSystem[application]
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$5.isSatisfiedBy(Pattern.java:5251)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$5.isSatisfiedBy(Pattern.java:5251)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$5.isSatisfiedBy(Pattern.java:5251)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$CharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3776)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:4250)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4234)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$CharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3777)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Begin.match(Pattern.java:3525)
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.match(Matcher.java:1270)
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.matches(Matcher.java:604)
    at sangria.schema.Named$.checkName(Schema.scala:115)
    at sangria.schema.Field$.apply(Schema.scala:339)
    at sangria.relay.Node$.globalIdField(Node.scala:67)
    at models.SchemaDefinition$.idFields(SchemaDefinition.scala:23)
    at models.SchemaDefinition$.FoodType$lzycompute(SchemaDefinition.scala:43)
    at models.SchemaDefinition$.FoodType(SchemaDefinition.scala:39)
    at models.SchemaDefinition$.TypeType$lzycompute(SchemaDefinition.scala:59)
    at models.SchemaDefinition$.TypeType(SchemaDefinition.scala:52)
    at models.SchemaDefinition$.FoodType$lzycompute(SchemaDefinition.scala:49)
    at models.SchemaDefinition$.FoodType(SchemaDefinition.scala:39)
    at models.SchemaDefinition$.TypeType$lzycompute(SchemaDefinition.scala:59)
    at models.SchemaDefinition$.TypeType(SchemaDefinition.scala:52)
    at models.SchemaDefinition$.FoodType$lzycompute(SchemaDefinition.scala:49)
    at models.SchemaDefinition$.FoodType(SchemaDefinition.scala:39)
    at models.SchemaDefinition$.TypeType$lzycompute(SchemaDefinition.scala:59)
    at models.SchemaDefinition$.TypeType(SchemaDefinition.scala:52)
    at models.SchemaDefinition$.FoodType$lzycompute(SchemaDefinition.scala:49)
    at models.SchemaDefinition$.FoodType(SchemaDefinition.scala:39)
    at models.SchemaDefinition$.TypeType$lzycompute(SchemaDefinition.scala:59)
    at models.SchemaDefinition$.TypeType(SchemaDefinition.scala:52)
    at models.SchemaDefinition$.FoodType$lzycompute(SchemaDefinition.scala:49)
    at models.SchemaDefinition$.FoodType(SchemaDefinition.scala:39)
    at models.SchemaDefinition$.TypeType$lzycompute(SchemaDefinition.scala:59)
    at models.SchemaDefinition$.TypeType(SchemaDefinition.scala:52)
    at models.SchemaDefinition$.FoodType$lzycompute(SchemaDefinition.scala:49)
    at models.SchemaDefinition$.FoodType(SchemaDefinition.scala:39)
    at models.SchemaDefinition$.TypeType$lzycompute(SchemaDefinition.scala:59)
    at models.SchemaDefinition$.TypeType(SchemaDefinition.scala:52)
    at models.SchemaDefinition$.FoodType$lzycompute(SchemaDefinition.scala:49)
    at models.SchemaDefinition$.FoodType(SchemaDefinition.scala:39)
    at models.SchemaDefinition$.TypeType$lzycompute(SchemaDefinition.scala:59)
    at models.SchemaDefinition$.TypeType(SchemaDefinition.scala:52)
    at models.SchemaDefinition$.FoodType$lzycompute(SchemaDefinition.scala:49)
    at models.SchemaDefinition$.FoodType(SchemaDefinition.scala:39)
    at models.SchemaDefinition$.TypeType$lzycompute(SchemaDefinition.scala:59)
    at models.SchemaDefinition$.TypeType(SchemaDefinition.scala:52)
```

Comment: You need to use a no-arg function when you are providing the list of fields. E.g. `() ⇒ idFields[TypeData] ++ ...`

Comment: Great. It's working now. I didn't notice that there is another apply that takes a function as fieldsFn. :-) Got the [output](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0LobSe-Oe1YQWNaMzVfRDBJajQ/view).